# Copy dlls to azure VM scale set to be used by other services at runtime

Tags: azure-service-fabric, mef

I am trying to use MEF to inject dlls in the services. What i cant figure out is how to copy those dlls to VM scaleset, so that the services can use those at runtime.

I want to automate this process, something like getting the dlls from blob storage and copying them to VM scale set or whenever a new VM is spawned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a new service (e.g. `FileService`) that holds these files. The service(s) using MEF would first call this `FileService` to get libraries (by name, package, version, etc.) and then load them. The `FileService` can keep them in its state, or use the blob store for persistence. (It also needs an API to manage the libraries.)

This will save you the complexity of getting files on your machines (on time) and keep using them like 'cattle'. It also doesn't block you from using containers in the future.